# Ant unable to launch, giving a main class error

Tags: java, ant

I'm running Elementary OS (Ubuntu 12 based), and I'm having issues running apache ant. It was working earlier before a restart, so I'm not sure what would've changed.

I've defined environment variables in /etc/environment as follows:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:$ANT_HOME/bin"
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-i386"
ANT_HOME="/opt/ant"
ANT_OPTS="-Xms256M -Xmx512M"
```

So my Java and Ant environment variables should be set. I'm trying to deploy with ant, with 'ant clean deploy', but I get an error in my terminal:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher
```

I've tried "source /etc/environment". Running 'echo $ANT_HOME' shows the correct path. I've tried moving ant to a different location and resetting the variables. Nothing. I'm kind of lost. Please help!

Comment: Did you define `ANT_HOME` _after_ you used it in your PATH?

Answer (score 7):

you should define $ANT_HOME before using it in your $PATH

```
  JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-i386"
  ANT_HOME="/opt/ant"
  PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:$ANT_HOME/bin"
```

double check that you have ant-launcher.jar under $ANT_HOME/lib

Comment: I've changed this, and it's giving me the same issue. I've noticed that /opt/ant/ doesn't actually have a 'bin' directory. Is this an issue? I didn't have one before and it was working...in the same vein, the path was being defined first, before $ANT_HOME, earlier and it was working fine.
Thanks for the reply.

Comment: what's the result of following 3 commands :
ant -version
whereis ant
ls -l /opt/ant

Comment: 'noah@work-VB:~/Work/liferay/ext$ ant -version
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher
noah@work-VB:~/Work/liferay/ext$ whereis ant
ant: /usr/bin/ant /usr/bin/X11/ant /usr/share/ant /usr/share/man/man1/ant.1.gz'

Comment: noah@work-VB:~/Work/liferay/ext$ ls -l /opt/ant
total 468
drwxr-xr-x 3 noah noah   4096 Oct 21 02:42 lib
drwxr-xr-x 7 noah noah   4096 Oct 21 02:42 manual
drwxr-xr-x 8 noah noah   4096 Oct 21 02:42 src
{showing directories only}

Apologies for poor formatting

Comment: do you have ant-launcher.jar under /opt/ant/lib

Comment: I didn't, after replacing it, I got this:
noah@work-VB:~/Work/liferay/ext$ ant -version
Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/lib/tools.jar
Failed to locateorg.apache.tools.ant.Main
ant.home: /opt/ant
Classpath: /opt/ant/lib/ant-launcher.jar:/usr/share/java/xmlParserAPIs.jar:/usr/share/java/xercesImpl.jar:/opt/ant/lib/ant-launcher.jar
Launcher JAR: /opt/ant/lib/ant-launcher.jar
Launcher Directory: /opt/ant/lib

Am I linking to the wrong jdk for my env variable

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, it looks like `ANT_HOME` isn't being set before you declare it in your path.

I take a slightly different approach to these things. Instead of constantly updating my PATH, I usually set my path to something fairly simple:

```
 PATH="/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin/:$HOME/bin"
```

Then, I make hard links to various binaries into my `/usr/local/bin` directory.

```
$ cd $ANT_HOME/bin  # All the Ant binaries
> for binary in *
> do
> sudo ln -s $PWD/$binary /usr/local/bin
> done
```

Now, I don't have to add `$ANT_HOME/bin` to my `$PATH`. Even better, if I include `/usr/local/bin` before `/usr/bin` and `/bin`, I am picking the binary in `/usr/local/bin` first. This way, I can ensure I run the version I installed over the default. For example, my machine comes with Ant 1.7 in `/usr/bin/ant` but I want to use Ant 1.9.1. I can install Ant 1.9.1, and that will be my default version.

Answer (score 0):

I had same error when install ant with npm install. When I tried install from official repository throw `pacman -S apache-ant`(`apt-get install apache-ant` -- for Debian/Ubuntu) it's start working proper for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing this bug with jdk 1.8. But, I came across this RHEL 6.5 bug for OpenJDK 1.8 which may be related:
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1149605

Essentially, it's fixed in jpackage-utils-1.7.5-3.13 which is included with RHEL 5.7.

The problem, as Javier Ramirez said in the bug comments:

> Your script `/usr/share/java-utils/java-functions` has problems with
>   "openjdk version" because it expects "java version" as Java 7 does.

```
$ mkdir /usr/share/java-1.8.0
$ mkdir /usr/lib/java-1.8.0
$ diff /usr/share/java-utils/java-functions.orig /usr/share/java-utils/java-functions
149,150c149,150
<             -e '/java \(full \)*version "/s/'$re'/<<<\1>>>/' \
<             -e '/java \(full \)*version "/s/.*<<<\([^>]\{1,\}\)>>>.*/\1/p')
---
>             -e '/[java|openjdk] \(full \)*version "/s/'$re'/<<<\1>>>/' \
>             -e '/[java|openjdk] \(full \)*version "/s/.*<<<\([^>]\{1,\}\)>>>.*/\1/p')

------
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using RHEL which comes with ant (in /usr/bin/ant) and the ant libraries in
/usr/share/ant. As suggest above, ant -version gave the "could not find" error.
I installed my own version of ant (in /home/Ant since I have a lot of space
in /home) and put ANT_HOME in my .bash_profile and $ANT_HOME/bin in my PATH
and $ANT_HOME and $ANT_HOME/bin (for good measure) in my CLASSPATH. Then ant
worked (when used as myself, not as root).